# Cross-Platform Rails Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Linux as my main Rails dev platform, but I also have Rails installed and working on my Windows pc. All my apps are synced between the two computers, so a change on Linux will reflect on Windows.

I'm wanting to use postgresql on Linux, but sqlite3 on Windows. Is there a way to distinguish certain gem sets to load (Gemfile) based on which platform I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bundler docs](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html)  does mentions about `:platform` option that you can use to specify which gems you want to install on certain platform.

There's another solution(I learned from other Ruby developers and online tutorials) is to wrap your gemset inside a group eg:

```
group :option do
  gem 'gem1'
  gem 'gem2'
  ...
end
```

Then run:

```
bundle install --without option
```

After you run this command, bundler will install gems that are not listed inside option group. You can set option to be either windows or linux. Hence the way to distinguish certain platform is solved.

Happy coding!

Comment: How would I setup the /db/database.yml file to work with one DB or the other (pg or sqlite)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommed to use postgresql on both machines (linux and windows) it will give you the same developer experience.
For instance, if you want to use smth postgresql specific you should consider this when running that code on windows/sqlite. I'm pretty sure you don't want to have different code base for windows and linux.

Anyway,
take a look at this question
[Multiple database.yml but one application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924658/multiple-database-yml-but-one-application)

Comment: The only problem with that is getting postgres to install on windows. I've had problems in the past and decided to just stick with sqlite3 on windows to save the hassle. Thanks for the comment and link though! Very helpful!